# Is it a single or double run?

Tags: savage-worlds

If a character runs and does a double move do they roll there running die twice?

IE if the character has Pace 6" and run d6 do they

1. Move **(6+d6)"** which takes a whole round
2. standard double move **12"**
3. Move **(2 times (6+d6))"**
4. Move **((6+d6)+(6+d6))"**

Comment: Baseball is off-topic for this stack. :)

Comment: Could you provide a source for a "standard double move"?  I've never heard of this in SW.

Comment: @Toast it looks like I merged concepts from the two systems we are playing in.

Comment: Happens all the time. =D I know DnD lets you take 2x and 4x move actions, but I've never seen it in SW.

Comment: Thanks to Groumy and SevenSidedDie (and Toast) for putting me right on the matter. Serves me right for playing Pathfinder on Tuesday and refereeing Savage Worlds on Wednesday. I am going to bless Groumy answer only as I have to choose one but SevenSidedDie is also correct and I like the All Out Move (from SevenSidedDie  answer) which I think I will House Rule into our games.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answers is:

> Move (6+d6)" which takes a whole round

The movement entry in the guide is quite clear on that. Here's what it says:

> **Movement**
>   Characters may move their full Pace (usually 6” for humans) in a round. This is considered a free action and doesn’t inflict a penalty to any other actions, such as firing a weapon or
>   taunting a foe.
>
> **Running**
>   A character may run an additional 1d6” during his turn if he wishes. Characters suffer a –2 penalty (the standard multiaction penalty) to all other actions made while running.

So all in all, there's no way you can double move in Savage Worlds. You can only move and run, because run is the only action that allows you move as an Action (since move is done as a free action).

And personally, I'd limit the number of running action to one, it's not stated in the rules that you can only do that once and, well, you never know when a min-maxer will try multiple runs a -X ...

Comment: You can *never* do the same action twice in a round (including Running), barring a few special cases, like shooting with a pistol in each hand. Also, it's worth noting that the Running Die cannot Ace, so you can't run half a mile in a single action.

Answer (score 4):

There's no such thing as a "double move". Movement in Savage Worlds isn't exactly part of the action economy – you either get your free move of your Pace in inches, or you run for a single extra 1d6" and take a -2 to your action(s). There is no "move" action, so you can't give up your standard action to get another "move" like you can in d20 systems.

The wording of the Run movement option is not explicit, but it's pretty clear that what it does is add a single +1d6", and it's *not* called an action. The wording never suggests that multiple "runs" are possible, but bringing in assumptions from other systems makes that easy to overlook. Running is just a special rule that stands on its own and doesn't fit into the general action rules.

---

If a normal move at 6" and running only increasing that to 7"-12" seems like running is not enough, you can make a new Setting Rule to give you the *effect* of a d20-style "double move" without opening up the can of worms that is being able to trade standard actions for more movement. (Because SW lets you take any number of actions if you accept the Multi-Action Penalty, that would either be pretty broken or require even more rules to balance it.)

The [*Shaintar Player's Guide*](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/109403/Shaintar%3A-Legends-Arise-%28Players-Guide%29) includes such a setting rule, if you want a freely-downloadable example. The **All Out Move** (p. 184) lets you move (2 × Pace) +1d6" in a generally straight line, at the expense of being the only thing you do that round* and making you much easier to hit in melee and with ranged weapons. This is pretty balanced, and means that in emergencies you can go pretty far, but it won't get used unless it's worth the risks.

<sup>* The one exception is if you have the new Shaintar Edge that allows you to specialise in Charging; then you can do a risky charge at the end  of an All Out Move.</sup>